# MariaDB "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mariadb, create-table

Browsed through other similar questions have not helped, I'm creating two simple tables and this error pops up, have no idea where it's gone wrong:

```
create table department (
    dept_name varchar(20),  
    building varchar(15),  
    budget numeric(12,2),  
    primary key (dept_name)
) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Now when I create second table:

```
create table course (
    course_id varchar(7), 
    title varchar(50), 
    dept_name varchar(20), 
    credits numeric(2,0), 
    primary key (course_id), 
    foreign key (dept_name) references department
) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=INNODB;
```

It gives me the error. What am I missing here?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please mention the error you're getting, so that others can help better!

Comment: Please make your post body self-contained, don't have something only in the title. Before considering posting chop code down until you get no error then add back--basic debugging. And when you haven't done that & post code it fails the "minimal" in [mre]. Also please research & reflect it. In particular for compier errors see the manual re grammar & try every case in each of many answers of each of many SO posts--it will be a duplicate or a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key syntax is:

```
foreign key (dept_name) references department(dept_name)
                       --  column name here --^
```